# How to loop twice over a list in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a string containing CSV content. I turned it into a list like so:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import csv

f = StringIO(list_csv)
my_list = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
```

Now I want to loop twice over the list, but the second time I try to loop, the code goes through as if the list was empty:

```
for item in my_list:
    code = item[1]
    print "code: "+code

for item in my_list:
    desc = item[2]
    print "desc: "+desc
```

(this code is simplified for demonstration purposes, I can't combine execution in a single loop)

I figured the list is still attached to the StringIO, and when it's done looping it's done reading, so it won't read again. Is there a one-liner to transform that into a regular list in the memory, that I could loop several times? I feel like running a loop manually copying values is reinventing the wheel.... but I can do that if there's no other option. Just asking for something less lengthy code-wise. Thanks!

Comment: my_list is a reader object, convert it to list, probably like this `new_list = list(my_list)` and loop over `new_list`

Comment: Thanks. You should've posted as an answer. ;) yeah.... that's how newb I am at python for now. :$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `my_list` is not actually a list. It is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) (actually a [reader object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#reader-objects) in this particular case, which is just a type of iterator).

An iterator is consumed after the first time all the values have been yielded. This is what is happening to `mylist`: after the first time you loop through it, the reader object has already been consumed and cannot be iterated again.

One solution is to store the contents in an actual `list` object. This should fix it:

```
my_list = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
```

...then proceed as before.

By the way if you are using a recent version of Python 3, there's a really nice syntax available for unpacking the iterator to a list:

```
my_list = [*csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this the following code:

```
my_list = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tee function in itertools, which can provide you more accesses into the iterator, not just once.

```
from itertools import tee

i1, i2 = tee(my_list)

for i in i1:
    pass

for i in i2:
    pass
```